# How do I get a ClassMirror on a Dart class?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

How do I get a ClassMirror using the Mirrors API? I tried using the top level `reflect()` function, but that takes a class instance, not a class as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a ClassMirror from an instance of the class, or from the library where the class was defined, or directly using the class name.

#### Obtaining a class mirror from an instance or an InstanceMirror

To obtain information about a class, you need a ClassMirror. To obtain a
ClassMirror, you first need an instance of the class, or the name of the
library where the class is defined.

If you have an instance, you can use the top level `reflectClass()` function
defined in the `dart:mirrors` library. This function returns a ClassMirror
object:

```dart
var classMirror = reflectClass(myObj.runtimeType);
MirrorSystem.getName(classMirror.simpleName); // 'MyClass'
```

If you have an InstanceMirror, use the InstanceMirror's `type` property to get
the ClassMirror:

```dart
var myObj = new MyClass();
var instanceMirror = reflect(myObj);
var classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
MirrorSystem.getName(classMirror.simpleName); // 'MyClass'
```

#### Obtaining a class mirror from a library mirror

If you know the name of the library where the class is defined, you can obtain
a mirror on that library, and then use the library mirror's `classes` property
to obtain a ClassMirror.  The `classes` property returns a map, where the keys
are the class names (expressed as Symbols), and the values are the associated
ClassMirror objects.

Here, for example, is how you can get a ClassMirror on the StringBuffer class
defined in the 'dart:core' library:

```dart
var mirrorSystem = currentMirrorSystem();
var libraryMirror = mirrorSystem.findLibrary(const Symbol('dart.core')).first;
var classMirror = libraryMirror.declarations[const Symbol('StringBuffer')];
MirrorSystem.getName(classMirror.simpleName); // 'StringBuffer'
```

Answer (score 3):

```dart
ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(Foo);
```

Comment: Quite correct, and I've modified the opening of my answer to allow for this method.